# How do you iterate over an array of objects for typeahead?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I want to use the bootstrap's typeahead, and search two different key-pairs in an object. How do I iterate over an array objects?

Also could someone explain what for is this?
`typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue"`

The `for` clause is throwing me off and it seems really unclear because `state for state` shares the same name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`state for state in states` is the comprehension expression, short for

```
angular.forEach(states, function (state) {
    return state;
});
```

You can take a look at the documentation about the comprehension expression introduced at [ngOptions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select) of select directive.

Comment: Is there a way to show two key pairs? For ex, the typeahead would show `Steven, 123345` with `{name: Steven, phone: 123345}`?

Comment: You can do `(person.name + ', ' + person.phone) for person in people`

Comment: I noticed that it would show just a comma in the input box. How do I not have it do that?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKqQM/8/ - So there's a comma, and I noticed it stops filtering the list when you're typing.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry I missed your comment. So the ngmodel has to be the object of `toy` defined in the expression. So it makes sense if you assign it with a toy object. http://jsfiddle.net/ZKqQM/9/

Comment: Thanks! There were still a few issues, like the typeahead wasn't filtering the list properly. I ended up just going with a different UX.