# Customisation of the typeahead feature in angular-ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I would like to use the angular-bootstrap-ui typeahead feature with the $http object.
A simple use case is found at the following plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eGG9Kj?p=preview

1. How do I manipulate the returned json BEFORE it is being rendered?
   I will be working with a more comlex json structure than a simple array.
2. How to overwrite the html-template being used so I can apply my own styles?
3. In case no results are found an empty typeahead-dropdown is shown. How do i avoid this?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

For questions (1) and (2) I believe that this is duplicate of [Bootstrap-UI Typeahead display more than one property in results list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18245834/1418796). Have a look at the answers in there that provide solutions to customizing various part of results displaying, including template override.

If the above doesn't solve your issue please update your question.

For (3) - it this example it is a back-end issue since it returns `[""]` where there are no matches while it should return `[]`. So it has nothing to do with the typeahead directive - just make sure that your backend returns empty array when there are no matches.