# Angular UI Bootstrap scope variables in custom typeahead template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap's typeahead directive, and added my own popup template via `typeahead-popup-template-url`. In that template, I'd like to access scope variables from the parent template (i.e. the one in which I've used the typeahead directive). Is this possible?

Here's a (broken) example of what I'm trying to do ("hello" should be present in the dropdown): http://plnkr.co/edit/ITT1SdRfUWeeN6n3aMqu?p=preview

I'd like to do this WITHOUT modifying the typeahead directive. I don't want to muck around in third party (uib) code if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, you need to reference the $parent scope. Change:

```
This should say "hello": {{hello}}</h1>
```

To:

```
This should say "hello": {{$parent.hello}}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there'd be a simple solution.

Comment: you might need to go up several parent scopes to get there. it took `$parent.$parent.$parent` for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441928/access-controller-scope-from-bootstrap-ui-typeahead-template/31727911

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap, jquery ui, kendoui, yui etc
Isn't that a bit much of frameworks together O.o

Anyway this post might help: [How to access parent scope from within a custom directive *with own scope* in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like this would require modifying the uib directive code? See my question for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe write a custom directive besides the original based on the original? Not too much experience with angular to know if that is possible and a good idea though.