# AngularJS UI Typeahead - Styling one of the properties of the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-typeahead

I've been using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245834/bootstrap-ui-typeahead-display-more-than-one-property-in-results-list) to guide me through using the fantastic typeahead directive.

I'm a little stuck however. I need to apply styling to ONE of the properties on the results.

I have a `plunker` [here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgd1eUJdpqbz2DJPSikl?p=preview)

My problem is that I don't really understand how a class could be applied to the supervisor.address property that is displayed at the end of the results.

`HTML` is below.

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
        <div>Selected: <span>{{selected}}</span></div>
        <div><input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="supervisor as supervisor.firstname +' '+supervisor.surname+''+' ('+supervisor.address+')' for supervisor in supervisors | filter:{firstname: $viewValue}:startsWith | limitTo: 8" typeahead-template-url="itemTpl.html"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the typeahead template in the plunkr?

Comment: I do apologise, I linked to the wrong plunker. This is now updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in your plunker:

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="match.model.firstname+' '+match.model.surname+''+' (<i>'+match.model.address+'</i>)' | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
```

You don't necessarily have to use an i tag.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I extend this to the input value once it is selected?

Comment: Nevermind just realised this isn't possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the results elements to do that:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemTpl.html">
 <a tabindex="-1">
    <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="match.model.firstname+' '+match.model.surname+''  |  typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
    <span style="font-weight: bold;" ng-bind-html-unsafe="'(' + match.model.address +')' | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
 </a>
</script>
```

Good luck