# How to make bootstrap typeahead template to use scope parameter in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I made a plunker to illustrate the issue:

```
"http://plnkr.co/edit/jqyCFv5R5pFMcYZe7kkP?p=preview"
```

Basically, I have a list of names with first and last name. I want to allow user to choose filter by first name or last name only or both of them. I could manage the filter to work, however, on UI, I'd like to avoid highlight if filter is not selected for the field. For example, if last name is not selected, it should not highlight the last name column. In plunker, I tried to use ng-show to hide unrelated, but it doesn't work. It looks I can't access scope parameter from the template. So, how to fix the problem?

Comment: why you dont want create sepereate directive ? and write your template in part of the directive and assign controller, in that case scope will be accessable

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to pull out your source into a function call and inject the extra variables into the result:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="item as item.label for item in filterTitles($viewValue, filterFirst, filterLast)" typeahead-template-url="itemTpl.html" />
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.filterTitles = function(filterText, shouldFilterFirst, shouldFilterLast){
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.titles.length;i++){
      var title = $scope.titles[i];
      if((shouldFilterFirst && title.first.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) >= 0) || (shouldFilterLast && title.last.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) >= 0))
        result.push({
          first: title.first, 
          last: title.last, 
          shouldFilterFirst: shouldFilterFirst, 
          shouldFilterLast: shouldFilterLast
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

[Simple plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBt81vLcuvIZ8GbgvGmV)

This could be done much more elegantly, but hopefully the idea is conveyed.