# Combine two variables to a label

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I have a typeahead attribute at an input field that looks like this:

```
typeahead="user.email as user.lastname for user in uc.userList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
```

so, I bind the email address by using the last name as a label for the typeahead function. Is there any possibility to combine two variables to a label like so:

```
typeahead="user.email as (user.firstname AND user.lastname) for user in uc.userList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
```

Comment: Have you try `typeahead-template-url` ?

Comment: nope, I will take a look at this :)

Comment: What typeahead library are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap UI

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution for this problem is to actually concat both values by simple string operators like so:

```
typeahead="user.email as user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname for user in uc.userList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
```

Furthermore, one can use templating techniques like typeahead-template-url, which are explained in more detail here: [Bootstrap-UI Typeahead display more than one property in results list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245834/bootstrap-ui-typeahead-display-more-than-one-property-in-results-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `typeahead-template-url` also:

```
<div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" 
    typeahead="user.email for user in userList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
    typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html">
</div>
```

And you have add your required columns in the template file:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
 <a>
  <span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.firstName | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  <span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.lastName | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
 </a>
</script>
```

Sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7zJ9wLoB5Y5lM0lwh10