# Angular UI typeahead doesn't populate textbox upon selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am using Angular UI [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive. I have a list of people that are in the typeahead dropbox. The list of people is an array of objects with properties like `LastName`, `FirstName`, `CustomerNumber`, etc. (Note, that my domain is completely different, and this is a simplification for clarity). Everything works fine if I have the following typeahead control:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedCustomer"
    typeahead-append-to-body="true"
    uib-typeahead="i.LastName for i in vm.lstCustomers | filter:$viewValue" />
```

However, I want to show more customer information in the typeahead dropbox. Let's say, I have a function in the controller:

```
vm.getFullName = function(customer) {
    return customer.LastName + ", " + customer.FirstName + " - " + customer.CustNumber;
    }
```

and corresponding directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedCustomer"
    typeahead-append-to-body="true"
    uib-typeahead="vm.getFullName(i) for i in vm.lstCustomers | filter:$viewValue" />
```

Once the selection is made, the model gets populated correctly; however text box shows `undefined, undefined - undefined` (curiously, the structure looks like `getFullName()` was applied to an empty value - with comma and dash).

If I go through every element of lstCustomers and apply getFullName(), everything looks fine again:

```
var lstCustomersFlat = [];
for (i = 0; i < vm.lstCustomers.length; i++) {
  var customer = vm.getFullName(vm.lstCustomers[i]);
  lstCustomersFlat.push(customer);
}
```

But I shouldn't have to do that, should I? Am I missing something, or I stumbled upon a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as shown below.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedCustomer"
    typeahead-append-to-body="true"
    uib-typeahead="i as vm.getFullName(i) for i in vm.lstCustomers | filter:$viewValue" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Not only it solved my problem, but it actually produces better model. I clearly need to get better understanding of `select` directive syntax!

Comment: Sampath, if you don't mind, could you point me to a place where this syntax is documented? Angular UI *refers to* "select as label for value in sourceArray" - but I can't find where it would go into actual definition... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you can find out some variations of its usage :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245834/bootstrap-ui-typeahead-display-more-than-one-property-in-results-list