# Chips autocomplete for Angular 1.6. No angular-material

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-ui-bootstrap, webpack-2

I would need to add an autocomplete chips component in our `Angular 1.6` application. We are using `Typescript`, `Webpack 2`. As we are already using `angular-ui-bootstrap`, we do not want to introduce also angular-material in order to avoid style conflicts. However the wished result is exactly what material chips provide.

Is there a directive or component that i can use in my case? I found [this library](https://github.com/mohbasheer/angular-chips) but it runs endless exceptions when I import it.

unfortunately I could find only partial solutions with bootstrap typehead, but then I would need to implement all the "chips" part, making me think of re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Newb here.  I have an identical problem as yours.  Here's how I resolved this:

**1. Resolve the `ReferenceError: error is not defined` within the angular-chips library**

The library you used (angular-chips) wasn't designed with typescript in mind.  So, you'll first need to resolve the following error `ReferenceError: error is not defined` by defining it for them in the line above with `var error;`.  This should prepare angular-chips for your webpack useage.

The second issue you'll find is how to add your `typeahead-template-url` with webpack in the mix.  Rather than referring to a separate html file, use an inline template as referenced here: [Bootstrap-UI Typeahead display more than one property in results list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245834/bootstrap-ui-typeahead-display-more-than-one-property-in-results-list/18251561#18251561).

If you're lazy like me and don't want to follow that hyperlink, use this as example:

**2. Template to be added before the `<chips>` tag:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="yourTemplate.html">
    <a tabindex="-1">
      <i ng-class="'icon-'+match.model.type"></i>
      <span  ng-bind-html-unsafe="match.model.title | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
   </a>
</scrip>
```

**3. Include template in your directive:**

```
typeahead-template-url:"yourTemplate.html"
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by using another library: ngTagsInput (http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) and it worked without any issues and workarounds.