# Bootstrap -UI typeahead showing more than 1 field on the results list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

So, I'm having the same issue present on this question

[Bootstrap-UI Typeahead display more than one property in results list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245834/bootstrap-ui-typeahead-display-more-than-one-property-in-results-list)

And, I already modified the plunker on the answer to my linking and needs

http://plnkr.co/edit/FdkvCUUD3ob7dt256Bgd?p=preview

But then, I realize they are using the 0.5 version of angular-ui, and angular 1.0.5

On my project, i'm using angular 1.4.9 and anguilar-ui 1.3.3 but somehow, my results are not showing or show as undefined

Controller

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sites = JSON.parse("[{\"SITE_CODE\":\"CODE1\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"NAME1\",\"ADDRESS\":\"\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"CODE2\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"NAME2\",\"ADDRESS\":\"\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"CODE3\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"NAME3\",\"ADDRESS\":\"\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"CODE4\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"NAME4\",\"ADDRESS\":\"\"}]");
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="typeahead">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="test" uib-typeahead="site as site.SITE_CODE for site in sites"
                       typeahead-no-results="noResults" typeahead-popup-template-url="siteList.html" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="noResults">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="siteList.html">
    <div class="row">
        <a tabindex="-1">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="match.model.SITE_CODE | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="match.model.SITE_NAME | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: where is your template `itemTpl.html`?

Comment: right at the bottom, it's named `siteList.html`, but I just realized, I'm setting up a popup instead of a normal template one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I just found out my issue

I was setting `typeahead-popup-template-url` instead of `typeahead-template-url`

After making this change, and adding `ngSanitize` to my module, everything went better than expected.

Now, I need to figure out a way to show the total of results, as I'll be only showing a fraction to the amount of results